# Searchable: Always show scope bar

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am currently stuck on a problem on how to show the scope bar all the time even when the user is not searching regarding a list with the `.searchable` modifier. iOS 16.4 recently added a `.searchScopes` [modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/anyview/searchscopes(_:activation:_:)) with an activation [parameter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/searchscopeactivation), but there's no option to have the scope bar always present itself. In addition, this modifier is not backported to previous versions of iOS 16, so it's basically unusable for my case.

UIKit has a similar [property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller/scopebaractivation), but it also has a `manual` case that allows for the developer to say whether the scope bar should be shown or not (which is what I want).

Is there any way to make the scope bar always show itself on iOS 16? I am open to ideas using third party packages as well such as SwiftUI-Introspect.

I am also aware that I can place a segmented picker on top of the list in a VStack, but this breaks animations when a user taps on the search bar which is why I want to try avoiding it.

```swift
enum SearchScope: String, CaseIterable {
    case inbox, message
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var searchText: String = ""
    @State private var searchScope: SearchScope = .inbox

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(1..<30) { num in
                    Text(String(num))
                }
            }
            .searchable(text: $searchText)
            .searchScopes($searchScope, activation: .onSearchPresentation) {
                ForEach(SearchScope.allCases, id: \.self) { scope in
                    Text(scope.rawValue.capitalized)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Search")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution of this?